# ASP.Net show splash image during background compilation

Tags: c#, asp.net, splash-screen

After compiling the entire asp.net project, when the first time the default.aspx page loads, asp.net compiles the pages into *Temporary Asp.Net* directory. This takes a long time during which I want to show a loading gif to the user.

Using a javascript on the default.aspx does not work as the page is practically not constructed yet. To get around this I created another page, say startup.html, that loads the splash and loads the default.aspx using windows.location.replace function.

This works but seems kludgy, Is there a better way of doing this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .load {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 9999;
            background: url("images/loading.gif") no-repeat center center rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" async>
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.replace("default.aspx");
        }, 100);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="load" />
</body>
</html>
```